# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TreeTagger'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to use the **Python** wrapper for `TreeTagger`, a Part-of-Speech Tagger. The code I use for importing and invoking the wrapper is:

```
import TreeTaggerWrapper
tagger = TreeTaggerWrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en',TAGDIR='D:/Programme/TreeTagger')
tags = tagger.TagText("This is a very short text to tag.")
print tags
```

the error is: `'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TreeTagger''`

The **init**.py exists in the TreeTaggerWrapper directory and is empty.

How would I go about systematically resolving the issue?

Comment: Is it called `init.py` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: it's with the underscores

Comment: Do you have a file TreeTaggerWrapper.py?

Comment: The file is called treetaggerwrapper.py, the directory is called TreeTaggerWrapper

Comment: Can you open `treetaggerwrapper.py` and see if there is a class named `TreeTagger` inside?

Comment: yes: class TreeTagger (object) :

Comment: How did you even get TreeTagger to work natively, i'm getting this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this wrapper:

http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/team/~panchenko/def/treetaggerwrapper.py

There is documentation inside the file.

**Update**

Copy the file `treetaggerwrapper.py` to `python/Lib`.

Try this:

```
import treetaggerwrapper
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en',TAGDIR='D:/Programme/TreeTagger')
tags = tagger.TagText("This is a very short text to tag.")
print tags
```

**Update 2**

If you have `Lib/site-packages/TreeTaggerWrapper/treetaggerwrapper.py`, then you should do this:

```
from TreeTaggerWrapper import treetaggerwrapper
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en',TAGDIR='D:/Programme/TreeTagger')
tags = tagger.TagText("This is a very short text to tag.")
print tags
```

Comment: ok. it worked. now, I should attempt to understand why: there are two things different that I can tell, one is the wrapper itself, which doesn't include de XML tags from the original and the other is that I just plunked the file into Lib, instead of Lib/site-packages/TreeTaggerWrapper. the latter should have worked, since I tried it with a simple packaging before. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot for your help.